# WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace

Tags: javascript, jenkins, kubernetes, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

My stage sonarqube always fails to run the job, I've made sure the server is correct.

Console output

```
Started by user Jesaya Fernando Napitupulu
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git http://10.8.60.132/jesaya/simple-webapp.git
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: kubernetes jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c
[Normal][jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c][Scheduled] Successfully assigned jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c to microk8s-worker
[Normal][jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c][Pulled] Container image "docker.io/library/openjdk:11.0.14.1-jre" already present on machine
[Normal][jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c][Created] Created container jdk
[Normal][jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c][Started] Started container jdk
[Normal][jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.11-1-jdk11" already present on machine
[Normal][jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][jenkins/xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c][Started] Started container jnlp
Agent xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c is provisioned from template xjoj_61-kw27q-npzb8
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations:
    buildUrl: "http://10.8.60.132:8880/job/'joj/61/"
    runUrl: "job/'joj/61/"
  labels:
    jenkins: "slave"
    jenkins/label-digest: "f4a24cf79b1ba88f85dc929f1365e192a6cbf6ee"
    jenkins/label: "xjoj_61-kw27q"
  name: "xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c"
  namespace: "jenkins"
spec:
  containers:
  - image: "docker.io/library/openjdk:11.0.14.1-jre"
    name: "jdk"
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  - env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c"
    - name: "JENKINS_WEB_SOCKET"
      value: "true"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "http://10.8.60.132:8880/"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.11-1-jdk11"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      limits: {}
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"

Running on xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/'joj
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential fcf5851b-d66d-4536-9c17-c298d681ff4b
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository http://10.8.60.132/jesaya/simple-webapp.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/'joj # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://10.8.60.132/jesaya/simple-webapp.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GitLab - @jesaya
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- http://10.8.60.132/jesaya/simple-webapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
Checking out Revision 7754fca1b5b3bfba7bbb856c933fda5f4704d9ae (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config remote.origin.url http://10.8.60.132/jesaya/simple-webapp.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 7754fca1b5b3bfba7bbb856c933fda5f4704d9ae # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 24d08d802f19788bd1273eb9a384d1fad98d8048 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (SAST)
[Pipeline] tool
Unpacking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/4.7.0.2747/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747.zip to /home/jenkins/agent/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar-scanner on xjoj-61-kw27q-npzb8-x2q9c
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withSonarQubeEnv
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: sonarqube-server
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/'joj@tmp/durable-b5831242
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
[Pipeline] // withSonarQubeEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```

Configuration of my sonarqube server:

[image]

Configuration of my sonar scanner tool:

[image]

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            cloud 'kubernetes'
            namespace 'jenkins'
            yaml'''
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Pod
            spec: 
              containers:
              - name: jdk
                image: docker.io/library/openjdk:11.0.14.1-jre
                tty: true
            '''
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('SAST') {
            environment {
                SCANNER_HOME = tool 'sonar-scanner'
            }
            steps {
                withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube-server') {
                    sh" ${SCANNER_HOME}}/bin/sonar-scanner \
                    -Dsonar.projectKey=simple_webapp \
                    -Dsonar.sources=. "
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant software version:

```
Sonarqube scanner: 4.7.0 2747
Sonarqube server: 8.9.8.54436
Jenkins: 2.332.2
Kubernetes (MicroK8s): 1.23.5-2+c812603a312d2b
Sonarqube Scanner plugin for Jenkins: 2.14
Kubernetes plugin for Jenkins: 3580.v78271e5631dc
```

This pipeline only runs a sonar scanner to scan my node.js code. For the Jenkins themselves, they run on a slave architecture.

Does anyone understand where this pipeline is going wrong? Console output does not provide a clear output of the error.

Comment: I can see a double `}` at the end of `SCANNER_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

```
steps {
  withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube-server') {
      sh" ${SCANNER_HOME**}**}/bin/sonar-scanner \
      -Dsonar.projectKey=simple_webapp \
      -Dsonar.sources=. "
  }
}
```

remore the extra } after SCANNER_HOME

Answer (score 0):

This happens when sonar.projectBaseDir configuration points to a folder which is different than the working folder of your build.
In my case, this was due to customized ant target which modified the parameter sonar.projectBaseDir.
Check the workspace output for folder ".scannerwork". It should contain report-task.xml.
There are 2 options to fix this:

- make sure sonar.projectBaseDir matches the folder from which you execute the sonar check
- add a script step to move the generated .scannerwork folder to your working folder.